# replace the $ in php variable declaration

Tags: php, syntax, bison, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to extend the `php` syntax, in order to tell apart mutable and immutable variables.

`$a` should be declared mutable (as in standard php)
and `#b` should be declared immutable.

I've read [Hacking PHP syntax](http://systemsarchitect.net/hacking-php-syntax/),

and I couldn't figure out where can I define that variables declared with `#` should also be tokenized as `T_VARIABLE` ?

Comment: These seem promising: [zend_language_parser.y](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/438d17e74e3ed7c4c8356a894057200d3b62f425/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L1117) , [Search for `T_Variable`](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=T_Variable&type=Code)

Comment: Keep in mind that # is also a comment character in PHP... Is there any reason why you wan't to implement this? Wouldn't an immutable variable act like a definition in most cases?

Comment: An immutable variable does not behave like `php`'s `define()`, since you can set its value multiple times, but you cannot change it's value. 

for example 
`#a=array(1,2);#a=array(1,3);`
 is valid,
whereas 
`#a=array(1,2);#a[1]=3;`
 is not.

Comment: Knowing which variables are immutable (and as a result, which functions are pure) could be used for caching and parallelism

Comment: Couldn't you achieve basically the same with Hungarian notation? Unless you rewrite large swaths of PHP and introduce a couple of new types, it does not actually have immutable values, nor would anything take advantage of this information. So `#b` would merely be a notational convention. You could get this with `$_b` or `$immB` or whatever other convention you think of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue,
Two steps need to be taken:

## Make `PHP` not parse `'#'` as comments:

Change:

```
<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>"#"|"//" {
```

To

```
<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>"//" {
```

In line 1901 in [zend_language_scanner.l](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/306a0f28d0a7591cb959793b71e8ebaeae85ed3b/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#L1901)

## Tokenize `#a` as a variable:

Change:

```
simple_variable:
T_VARIABLE { $$ = $1; }
| '$' '{' expr '}' { $$ = $3; }
| '$' simple_variable { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_VAR, $2); }
;
```

To:

```
simple_variable:
T_VARIABLE { $$ = $1; }
| '$' '{' expr '}' { $$ = $3; }
| '$' simple_variable { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_VAR, $2); }
| '#' '{' expr '}' { $$ = $3; }
| '#' simple_variable { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_VAR, $2); }
;
```

In line 1117 of [zend_language_parser.y](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/438d17e74e3ed7c4c8356a894057200d3b62f425/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L1117)

## That's it

Now this code works:

```
#a=1;
echo (#a);//1
```

Answer (score -2):

My first guess was to see if you could change this in your php.ini file for your project however there is not an option that allows you to change the sign.  http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

My best guess would be that you would need to look in the actual PHP code base or ask the PHP community if they would add this feature for you.

Comment: That's what he's asking about: where to change this in the PHP code base.